# В слове "кальмар" все согласные звонкие?

Tags: фонетика, согласные

Правда ли, что в слове "кальмар" все согласные звонкие?

Comment: @Пошка, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Все, за исключением первого согласного - ***К***.